# Preloader Is Showing The Contents Of The Webpage Before Fully Loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was making a preloader for my website, in which an animation is shown but the problem is that the preloader shows some of the content of the website without even fully loading the code, like this,

[image: The Screenshot Of The Loader]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<div class="self-container" style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
 <title>Diary Entry</title>

 <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Fonts -->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="font-family: 'Permanent Marker'">Archlight</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
     
       <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link" href="/create/">Create New Entry <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link" href="/profile/">Profile <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           Other
         </a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout/">Logout</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
           <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
         </div>
       </li>
     
     </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
 <br>
 <br>
 

<div class="page">
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href = "/static/diary/updatepage.css">
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/tqa92zf2lukln0ritoavtb2b9ospf6898jnd0senmv5ahfk9/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js"></script>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Loading Animation</title>
 <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <style>

 .preload{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: deepskyblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
 }

 .loading{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: opacity 0.5 ease;
 }

 h1.text{
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
 }

 .preload-finish{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
 }


 .obj{
  width: 6px;
  height: 4px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  animation: loading 0.8s infinite;
 }

 .obj:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
 }

 .obj:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
 }

 .obj:nth-child(4){
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
 }

 .obj:nth-child(5){
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
 }

 .obj:nth-child(6){
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
 }

 .obj:nth-child(7){
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
 }

 .obj:nth-child(8){
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
 }

 @keyframes loading {
  0%{
   height: 0;
  }
  50%{
   height: 40px;
  }
  100%{
   height: 0;
  }
 }


 </style>
 <div class="preload">
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <h1 class="text">Archlight</h1>
 </div>
 <script>
  window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
   const preload  = document.querySelector(".preload");
   preload.classList.add("preload-finish");
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Sidebar</title>
</head>
<body>
 <style>
  /*Sidebar*/

  #SideBar{
   position: fixed;
   width: 245px;
   height: 100%;
   background: #151719;
   left: -245px;
   transition: all 500ms linear;
  }
  #SideBar.active{
   left:0px;
  }
  #SideBar ul li{
   color: rgba(230,230,230,0.9);
   list-style: none;
   padding: 15px 10px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
  }

  #SideBar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
  }

  #SideBar ul{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  li.first{
    margin-top: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
  }

  #SideBar .toggle-btn{
   position: absolute;
   left: 253px;
   top: 30px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }


  .toggle-btn{
    cursor: pointer;
    width:20px;
    height:4px;
    background:white;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .4s;
  }

  .toggle-btn::after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background:white;
    width:20px;
    height:4px;
    top: 7px;
    transition: all .4s;
  }

  .toggle-btn::before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background:white;
    width:20px;
    height:4px;
    bottom: 7px;
    margin-left: 0;
    transition: all .4s;
  }

  .menu.active .toggle-btn::after {
    transform: rotateZ(55deg) translate(-8px, 0px);
    background:red;
  }

  .menu.active .toggle-btn::before {
    transform: rotateZ(-55deg) translate(-7px, 0px);
    background:red;
  }

  .menu.active .toggle-btn {
    background:transparent;
  }
 </style>
<div id="what" class="SideBar">
 <div id="SideBar">
 <div class="menu">
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSideBar()">
     <script>
     const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

     menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
     menu.classList.toggle("active");
   })</script>
    </div>
 </div>
    <ul>
     <li class="first link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="link">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function toggleSideBar(){
    document.getElementById("SideBar").classList.toggle('active');
   }
  </script>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
  <br>
 <div class="main-box">
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="JQ0xl4HmM1EkPrY4yWEX9PaTx2cOt5gPk0EOR4rbUuJ9Ur5ilPPolcooTgdauW1p">
  
  
  <span><small>
  
  </small></span>
  <br>
  
  <span><input type="text" name="title" value="Waiting" maxlength="50" class="title" required id="id_title"><input type="hidden" name="initial-title" value="Waiting" id="initial-id_title"></span>
  <a href="/entry/6/delete" class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i></a>
  
  
  <span><small>
  
  </small></span>
  <br>
  
  <span><textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="10" id="content" class="content" required>
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Still, Believe It&#39;s Bad?&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Waiting is probably my green day&#39;s favorite song!&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;div style=&quot;color: #222222; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;&quot;&gt;I&#39;m the son of rage and love&lt;br /&gt;The Jesus of Suburbia&lt;br /&gt;The bible of none of the above&lt;br /&gt;On a steady diet of&lt;br /&gt;Soda Pop and Ritalin&lt;br /&gt;No one ever died for my&lt;br /&gt;Sins in hell&lt;br /&gt;As far as I can tell&lt;br /&gt;At least the ones that I got away with&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;secrsf&quot; style=&quot;margin-top: 13px; color: #222222; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;&quot;&gt;And there&#39;s nothing wrong with me&lt;br /&gt;This is how I&#39;m supposed to be&lt;br /&gt;In a land of make-believe&lt;br /&gt;That don&#39;t believe in me&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;secrsf&quot; style=&quot;margin-top: 13px; color: #222222; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;&quot;&gt;Get my television fix&lt;br /&gt;Sitting on my crucifix&lt;br /&gt;The living room in my private womb&lt;/div&gt;</textarea></span>
  
  
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 <script>tinymce.init({
 selector:'textarea',
 plugins: "autoresize",
   min_height: 500,
 inline_boundaries: false,
 setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function (e) {
            editor.save();
        });
    }
 });
 </script>
</div>

</div>

 <!-- JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In The Above Image, Waiting, the trash icon and the hamburger icon are part of my webpage's content which shouldn't show up.

My Preloader Code:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    const preload  = document.querySelector(".preload");
    preload.classList.add("preload-finish");
   });
```

```css
.preload{
   font-family: sans-serif;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   background: deepskyblue;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  }

  .loading{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   height: 40px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   transition: opacity 0.5 ease;
  }

  h1.text{
   color: white;
   position: fixed;
   top: 20%;
  }

  .preload-finish{
   opacity: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
  }


  .obj{
   width: 6px;
   height: 4px;
   background: white;
   margin: 0 3px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   animation: loading 0.8s infinite;
  }

  .obj:nth-child(2){
   animation-delay: 0.1s;
  }

  .obj:nth-child(3){
   animation-delay: 0.2s;
  }

  .obj:nth-child(4){
   animation-delay: 0.3s;
  }

  .obj:nth-child(5){
   animation-delay: 0.4s;
  }

  .obj:nth-child(6){
   animation-delay: 0.5s;
  }

  .obj:nth-child(7){
   animation-delay: 0.6s;
  }

  .obj:nth-child(8){
   animation-delay: 0.7s;
  }

  @keyframes loading {
   0%{
    height: 0;
   }
   50%{
    height: 40px;
   }
   100%{
    height: 0;
   }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Loading Animation</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="preload">
   <div class="obj"></div>
   <div class="obj"></div>
   <div class="obj"></div>
   <div class="obj"></div>
   <div class="obj"></div>
   <div class="obj"></div>
   <div class="obj"></div>
   <div class="obj"></div>
   <h1 class="text">Archlight</h1>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

So, what I'm doing wrong that the hamburger icon, trash icon and 'Waiting' which is a textbox, by the way, is coming up?

Also, I can provide the code of the all thing, which includes the components of the web page, but most of my code is in Django(Python) which makes it unreadable, so I have to provide the page source code which is quite long. Anyways, the full page animation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<div class="self-container" style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
 <title>Diary Entry</title>

 <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Fonts -->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="font-family: 'Permanent Marker'">Archlight</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
     
       <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link" href="/create/">Create New Entry <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link" href="/profile/">Profile <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           Other
         </a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout/">Logout</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
           <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
         </div>
       </li>
     
     </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
 <br>
 <br>
 

<div class="page">
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href = "/static/diary/updatepage.css">
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/tqa92zf2lukln0ritoavtb2b9ospf6898jnd0senmv5ahfk9/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js"></script>
 <style>

.preload{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: deepskyblue;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.loading{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 height: 40px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 transition: opacity 0.5 ease;
}

h1.text{
 color: white;
 position: fixed;
 top: 40%;
}

.preload-finish{
 opacity: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
}


.obj{
 width: 6px;
 height: 4px;
 background: white;
 margin: 0 3px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 animation: loading 0.8s infinite;
}

.obj:nth-child(2){
 animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.obj:nth-child(3){
 animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.obj:nth-child(4){
 animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.obj:nth-child(5){
 animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.obj:nth-child(6){
 animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.obj:nth-child(7){
 animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.obj:nth-child(8){
 animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

@keyframes loading {
 0%{
  height: 0;
 }
 50%{
  height: 40px;
 }
 100%{
  height: 0;
 }
}


</style>
<div class="preload">
 <div class="obj"></div>
 <div class="obj"></div>
 <div class="obj"></div>
 <div class="obj"></div>
 <div class="obj"></div>
 <div class="obj"></div>
 <div class="obj"></div>
 <div class="obj"></div>
 <h1 class="text">Archlight</h1>
</div>
<script>
 window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  const preload  = document.querySelector(".preload");
  preload.classList.add("preload-finish");
 });
</script>
 
 <style>
  /*Sidebar*/

  #SideBar{
   position: fixed;
   width: 245px;
   height: 100%;
   background: #151719;
   left: -245px;
   transition: all 500ms linear;
  }
  #SideBar.active{
   left:0px;
  }
  #SideBar ul li{
   color: rgba(230,230,230,0.9);
   list-style: none;
   padding: 15px 10px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
  }

  #SideBar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
  }

  #SideBar ul{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  li.first{
    margin-top: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
  }

  #SideBar .toggle-btn{
   position: absolute;
   left: 253px;
   top: 30px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }


  .toggle-btn{
    cursor: pointer;
    width:20px;
    height:4px;
    background:white;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .4s;
  }

  .toggle-btn::after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background:white;
    width:20px;
    height:4px;
    top: 7px;
    transition: all .4s;
  }

  .toggle-btn::before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background:white;
    width:20px;
    height:4px;
    bottom: 7px;
    margin-left: 0;
    transition: all .4s;
  }

  .menu.active .toggle-btn::after {
    transform: rotateZ(55deg) translate(-8px, 0px);
    background:red;
  }

  .menu.active .toggle-btn::before {
    transform: rotateZ(-55deg) translate(-7px, 0px);
    background:red;
  }

  .menu.active .toggle-btn {
    background:transparent;
  }
 </style>
<div id="what" class="SideBar">
 <div id="SideBar">
 <div class="menu">
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSideBar()">
     <script>
     const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

     menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
     menu.classList.toggle("active");
   })</script>
    </div>
 </div>
    <ul>
     <li class="first link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="link">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function toggleSideBar(){
    document.getElementById("SideBar").classList.toggle('active');
   }
  </script>
  </div>
</div>
  <br>
 <div class="main-box">
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="kYg1P61kNzGOilvbYjVec6Gxtd7Dt1keV8Uil6L9V2LDnlCpLc6FotU2Pr8ZuS5O">
  
  
  <span><small>
  
  </small></span>
  <br>
  
  <span><input type="text" name="title" value="Waiting" maxlength="50" class="title" required id="id_title"><input type="hidden" name="initial-title" value="Waiting" id="initial-id_title"></span>
  <a href="/entry/6/delete" class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i></a>
  
  
  <span><small>
  
  </small></span>
  <br>
  
  <span><textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="10" id="content" class="content" required>
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Still, Believe It&#39;s Bad?&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Waiting is probably my green day&#39;s favorite song!&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;div style=&quot;color: #222222; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;&quot;&gt;I&#39;m the son of rage and love&lt;br /&gt;The Jesus of Suburbia&lt;br /&gt;The bible of none of the above&lt;br /&gt;On a steady diet of&lt;br /&gt;Soda Pop and Ritalin&lt;br /&gt;No one ever died for my&lt;br /&gt;Sins in hell&lt;br /&gt;As far as I can tell&lt;br /&gt;At least the ones that I got away with&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;secrsf&quot; style=&quot;margin-top: 13px; color: #222222; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;&quot;&gt;And there&#39;s nothing wrong with me&lt;br /&gt;This is how I&#39;m supposed to be&lt;br /&gt;In a land of make-believe&lt;br /&gt;That don&#39;t believe in me&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;secrsf&quot; style=&quot;margin-top: 13px; color: #222222; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;&quot;&gt;Get my television fix&lt;br /&gt;Sitting on my crucifix&lt;br /&gt;The living room in my private womb&lt;/div&gt;</textarea></span>
  
  
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 <script>tinymce.init({
 selector:'textarea',
 plugins: "autoresize",
   min_height: 500,
 inline_boundaries: false,
 setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function (e) {
            editor.save();
        });
    }
 });
 </script>
</div>

</div>

 <!-- JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Your preloader hides elements with the `preload` class until the site is ready. Did you give your navigation bar this class?

Comment: I didn't, but what even if I didn't give the navbar the class, so why it would interfere with the page's content?

Comment: You haven't shared your actual HTML, so it's hard to say, but presumably those elements (or their parents) need the `preload` class.

Comment: I've added the full page, I know It's lot of code, but it'll really be some help, if you can take a look.

Comment: You've got multiple `<head>` and `<body>` regions. This is very weird code.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I messed up a little, I wrote before that I didn't wrote this code, Python did, Now, I think that the mutliple `head` and `body` must have been fixed, right?